Unable to Broadcast SSE Events to All Clients in Rust
I'm working on a Rust project where I need to broadcast messages to multiple connected clients using Server-Sent Events (SSE). The setup allows clients to connect successfully, and they receive events when I send them manually. However, I'm having issues with broadcasting messages to all clients. Although the broadcast function is invoked, the clients don't receive the messages as expected.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use actix_web_lab::sse;
use futures_util::SinkExt;
use log::info;
use tokio::sync::mpsc::{self, channel};

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Default)]
pub struct SseClients {
    clients: Arc<Mutex<Vec<mpsc::Sender<sse::Event>>>>
}

impl SseClients {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        SseClients {
            clients: Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new())),
        }
    }

    pub async fn add_client(&self) {
        let (tx, rx) = channel(10);
        tx.send(sse::Data::new("connected").into()).await.unwrap();
        self.clients.lock().unwrap().push(tx);
        info!("New SSE connection established");
    }

    pub fn get_no_of_clients(&self) -> usize {
        self.clients.lock().unwrap().len()
    }

    pub async fn broadcast(&self, msg: &str) {
        let clients = self.clients.lock().unwrap().clone();
        for client in &clients {
            println!("{:?}", client);
        }
        info!("Broadcasting message");
        println!("Number of clients: {}", self.clients.lock().unwrap().len());

        let send_futures = clients.iter().map(|client| client.send(sse::Data::new(msg).into()));
        let _ = futures_util::future::join_all(send_futures).await;
    }
}

In my main function, I set up an Actix web server like this:


#[get("/sse")]
async fn new_sse_client(sse_clients: web::Data<Arc<SseClients>>) -> impl Responder{
//     add client heer
    sse_clients.add_client().await;
    format!("connected and the number of clients are {}",sse_clients.get_no_of_clients())
    #I can see this message properly on the web browser by opening http:://localhost:8080
}

#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    // Omitted: initializing server and sessions
    
    let server = ya_relay_server::run(&args, sse_clients.clone()).await?; # broadcast fucntion is triggered fom events in this function

    let sse_clients_clone = web::Data::new(sse_clients.clone());

    let web_server = actix_web::HttpServer::new(move || {
        use actix_web::*;

        App::new()
            .app_data(sse_clients_clone.clone())
            .service(new_sse_client)
            // other routes
    })
    .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
    .run()
    .await?;
}

The SSE connection is successfully established, and I can manually send events to clients. However, when I attempt to broadcast, I see the following output, but no messages appear on the client side:
Sender { chan: Tx { inner: Chan { tx: Tx { block_tail: ..., tail_position: ... }, semaphore: ..., rx_fields: "..." } } }
[INFO] Broadcasting message
Number of clients: 9
Disconnected

The broadcast function is clearly invoked, but I don’t know how to verify or receive the broadcasted messages on the client side.
What could be causing the clients to miss the broadcasted messages, and how can I resolve this issue? Do I need additional client-side handling or changes to the broadcast logic?

When a client disconnects and the receiving side of the channel gets dropped, what will happen when you invoke client.send()? What will this return? How will join_all react to this?
